# Modal en laravel, con etiqueta video funciona pero con iframe no cierra

Tags: laravel, modal, bootstrap-3

Tengo en una zona de mi web varios modals con videos y funcionan correctamente pero si sustituyo el < video> por < iframe> el video se va pero el fade no se cierra. aquí el código:

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6" style="padding: 10px;">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#hola" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="imagen de la miniatura"/>';
    <h4>titulo</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="hola" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog bideoa">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" onclick="cerrar()" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                //con este el iframe desaparece pero el fade de fondo no se cierra, se duplica
                <iframe src="link embed youtube" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                //con este todo funciona correctamente
                <video src="video.mp4" controls> video not supported </video> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function cerrar() {
        $("iframe").each(function () { this.pause() });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Puedes usar en tu función: `window.closeModal = function(){ $('#iframeModal').modal('hide'); };` o también `function cerrar(frameElement) { if (frameElement) { var dialog = $(frameElement).closest(".modal"); if (dialog.length > 0) { dialog.modal("hide"); } } }`. Avísanos cómo te va

Comment: no funcionan ninguna de las dos, es como que el iframe se enrolla como una persiana para arriba pero la transparencia negra el fade in no pasa a fade out para desaparecer, y es muy extraño porque solo ocurre si en su interior hay un iframe